# How to show the output of code samples interactively in blog posts on Blogger

Tags: blogger, blog

I have started a blog on Blogger [http://algorithmsolutions.blogspot.com/](http://algorithmsolutions.blogspot.in/)

Currently I'm posting code samples using Gist of GitHub.

Is there any way to show two windows in blog post, i.e., **Code** and **Output**, in which if any blog reader changes code in code area then it gets reflected automatically in the output area, just like the exercise window in courses of Khan Academy?

I need to post code snippets in C++ or Java.

Comment: this isn't possible natively on blogger.

Comment: You can link to the samples on online IDEs which also show the output - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/02/online-ides-for-c-frill-free-visual.html

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.sitepoint.com/embed-jsfiddle-code-web-pages/

Instructions
1. Go to jsfiddle.net and create your snippet
2. Navigate to Menu > Share > Embed Code (embeds in an iFrame).
3. Copy the iFrame code into your webpage HTML

Comment: Thank you for the reply ... I checked jsfiddle.net as per your answer. But it shows only HTML , JS and CSS . I need something for C++ or Java